# How can cameras with RTSP like Tapo cameras be accessible from the outside?

Tags: networking, lan, tunnel, rtsp

I wanted to know how these cameras work when it comes to redirecting traffic outside the local area network (LAN) of your home. In other words, you connect them to your phone, configure them, connect them to the internet, and then they are accessible from outside using the app. However, they never provide the RTSP address for you to use your own application. As far as I know, you always need to use their apps. I was curious to know how they work. Do they have something like No-IP built-in? Do they create a tunnel to a specific server? Additionally, is it possible to obtain those RTSP URLs? Or do Tapo servers handle all the traffic every time I want to connect to my camera through their app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those cloud services aren't a direct connection from the app to camera, as this would not be able to get in to the camera through NAT and router firewall. (Services like No-IP etc. only help giving a static address for a public IP that can change, but doesn't help in any way to bypass the router.)

Instead the camera sends an outgoing stream to their cloud server to which the app connects.

You can use the camera direct RTSP stream as described in https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/2680/, but if you want to access it remotely you'll need to take care of the port forwarding on the router.